# Find FreeBSD ports that depend on another port

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports, dependencies

I have a headless FreeBSD server where some port has installed tons of X11-related packages. I would like to find out what these ports are so I can get rid of the unwanted X-related packages. Is there a way to figure this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current accepted answer is out of date.  FreeBSD has replaced its legacy packaging tools with [pkgng](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html).

Here's the new way to query the reverse-dependencies of a package:

```
pkg info -r <pkg name>
```

Example:

```
root@server:/usr/ports # pkg info -r python27
python27-2.7.6_4:
        python2-2_2
        talloc-2.0.8
        tevent-0.9.18
        tdb-1.2.12,1
        ldb-1.1.16
        glib-2.36.3_2
        xcb-proto-1.9
        gobject-introspection-1.36.0_2
        samba4-4.0.13
```

Answer (score 4):

`pkg_info` answers questions like this. With the `-R` option it expects a name of an installed port and will display all ports that depend on that port:

```
pkg_info -R libXfont-1.4.3,1
```

You can use wildcards to avoid specifying the name with the version number:

```
pkg_info -R libXfont-\*
```

Note that this does not work recursively, and thus you need to do `pkg_info -R` again for each port in the resulting list until you get to the bottom of things.

Note that on servers it is often a good idea to put the following in `/etc/make.conf`:

```
WITHOUT_X11=yes
```

That will make most (all?) ports to skip dependencies to any X11 related stuff.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: In this community proper etiquette for expressing thanks is to upvote and accept answers. Since everything is kept as a permanent archive of question/answer pairs you don't need to clutter things up with thank you notes. Comments should only be used to add to or discuss the content of posts.

Answer (score 0):

While accepted answer is correct, there is a more robust and feature-rich variant that can provide you with more flexibility:

```
# pkg query %ro python27
misc/mc
devel/talloc
lang/python2
lang/python
devel/git
devel/tevent
databases/tdb
devel/py-setuptools
dns/py-dnspython
devel/py-iso8601
net/samba48
```

That would give you reverse dependencies for the locally installed ports. In some cases you may want to list ALL the existing dependencies on that port, in that case `pkg rquery` can give you that information:

```
# pkg rquery %ro python27|wc -l
    3758
```

Please consult `man pkg-query` for the full list of possible query flags, those should work for `pkg-rquery` as well.